# Javascript Reference error "$ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The script does not work, and the ebugging screen shows the error

> $ is not defined

```
<script href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()){
            $('nav').addClass('black');
        }else{
            $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })
```

Comment: A `<script>` tag should have a "src" attribute, not "href", to load an external script.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
<script href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

You must edit "href" to "src"

Comment: Glad to help. You are newbie of html?

Comment: Yes, i am! Can you help me with another jquery question?