# Jupyter Notebook / jupyternotify / Javascript Error: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**This is a not a full on JavaScript project like the following question/answers:**

- [Javascript Reference error "$ is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975152/javascript-reference-error-is-not-defined)
- [JavaScript/jQuery - "$ is not defined- $function()" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779148/javascript-jquery-is-not-defined-function-error)

This is a simple Jupyter notebook/lab expansion python package called "[jupyter-notify](https://github.com/ShopRunner/jupyter-notify)" that should generate a pop up "browser notification" after a cell finish running

**Previously it was installed via**

`pip install jupyternotify`

**CELL 1:**

`%load_ext jupyternotify`

**CELL 2:**

```
%%notify
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

**CELL 2 ERROR:**

`Javascript Error: $ is not defined`

**Goal**

- is to not to have this error and
- just  get a pop up message whenever a certain cell finishes running

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the UI of the jupyter notebook. Nothing about your code.

Comment: $ can be a shorthand for different things, mostly know jQuery - use F12 and see if you get more info in the debugging output

Comment: @PatrickArtner F12 everything looks pretty normal. (I have turned off all my browser extensions but that also have no resolved the issue).

Comment: Jupyternotify:  "This is currently tested avainst Chrome (58is Version) ..." ... Chrome is past 100 at this point in time.

Comment: I have the same issue, somebody help!